# build variable in jenkinsfile pipeline script for emailext

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I am trying to use build variable in presendScript of emailext in jenkinsfile pipeline script as below.

```
emailext body: "Pipeline error: Please go to ${BUILD_URL} and verify the build",
subject: "'${JOB_NAME}' (${BUILD_NUMBER}) failed",
presendScript: '''
    logger.print(build.getEnvironment());
   ''',
to: 'my email address'
```

Getting following error, upon running the build.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getEnvironment()
>   on null object    at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)

build variable is available when the same script is run as presendScript in freestyle project

I am not sure if I am not using build variable in appropriate context.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

If you want to add the environment to the body of the message, do the following:

```
sh echo "Pipeline error: Please go to ${BUILD_URL} and verify the build" > mail.txt
sh printenv >> mail.txt

emailext body: readFile 'mail.txt',
subject: "'${JOB_NAME}' (${BUILD_NUMBER}) failed",
to: 'your email address'
```

I'm not sure about the legacy Jenkins syntax; I'm more familiar with the declarative pipeline where you would do:

```
sh 'echo "Pipeline error: Please go to ${BUILD_URL} and verify the build" > mail.txt'
sh 'printenv >> mail.txt'
emailext (
  body: readFile('mail.txt'),
  subject: "'${JOB_NAME}' (${BUILD_NUMBER}) failed",
  to: 'your email address'
)
```